# How to use a token in "Behavior without results" of a view?

Tags: views, 8

I want to retrieve the ID token of the group in "Behavior without result" of a view. How to do ?

It only offers me (site and view).

[image]

The token does not work.

The url does not take ID into account:

/group//join

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check the checkbox and then use the token you want **BUT** you have to be careful because you are in the case you do not have any results and the `{{ id }}` will use the first result of your view as said on the description.

So you have to use your contextual filter : `{{ arguments.id }}` and it will work as you want.

Comment: I still have a problem with the token

Comment: See my edit, hope this helps.